# Globally Suppress JavaScript errors in ASP .NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an application which uses Updatepanels in ASP .NET

How can i globally suppress JavaScript exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried this .? Though this is not a good idea to suppress errors.

```
function silentErrorHandler() {return true;}
window.onerror=silentErrorHandler;
```

Comment: Sorry, where do I put this code? In the Master page?

Comment: You can put this inside head tag.
<script>
function silentErrorHandler() {return true;}
window.onerror=silentErrorHandler;
<script>

Comment: I have placed it in the Master page but there are still some JavaScript errors showing in the output window of Visual studio

Comment: It is a javascript code, so you need it inside <script></script> tag

Comment: I have put it in the <script type="text/javascript">function silentErrorHandler() { return true; }
        window.onerror = silentErrorHandler;
    </script> But on which page? The Master page??

Comment: Yes on the master page. so that this is code is available on every subpage.